# Ada compiler not installed on this system error after make in Fedora 16

Tags: gcc, ada, fedora16

I installed gcc 4.3.4 fine one fedora16 but my problem is to run ada program got error  `Ada compiler not installed on this system`. I think it crashes because of installed old version of gcc on gcc 4.6.3. How to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538813/ada-compiler-crashes

Comment: `gcc -c a.adb` calls the `gnat1` internal executable (`cc1` analogue for ADA). That does not come installed by default with GCC on most distributions.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely no problem to install multiple version of gcc. The problem is that the Ada compiler gnat depends on a specific gcc, e.g., gnat-4.x depends on gcc-4.x-

The file /usr/bin/gcc should be a symlink to the default gcc. Changing the symlink to 
the proper gcc (/usr/bin/gcc-4.6) can fix your problem. 
                         ^^^^^^^ 
                         proper gcc for gnat-4.6

If changing the symling does not work, reinstall (remove+install) the Ada compiler (gnat) again.