# Ada compiler crashes with "Ada compiler not installed on this system." after downgrading gcc version

Tags: linux, gcc, fedora, ada, gnat

I downgraded my gcc version 4.6.3 to 4.3.4 but ada version is not changed gnat-4.6.3 so I got error

> Ada compiler not installed on this system.

How to set my ada to gnat 4.3.4?

Comment: This is a decade ago and I hope you solved it. Maybe you didn't update your path environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what system you're running on and how you installed it. You need to either install GNAT from the same build of GCC, or you need to install GNAT in such a way that it doesn't interfere with the rest of GCC.

Comment: Thanks..I'm trying to install GNAT on  same GCC build but make file creates an error Makefile:62: ../gcc/libada-mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../gcc/libada-mk'.  Stop.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what type of system you're running, what version of GNAT you have installed or what type of configure statement you used, so I don't know how you can expect anyone to help you. Since GNAT is written in Ada, if you don't have GNAT working on your system already, you can't build a new version.

Comment: Hi..prosfilaes..i'm using x86_64 AMD machine, os=>fedora16 gcc=>4.3.4(as i configured),gcc-gnat and g++ =>4.6.3.Now i want to change gcc 4.6.3 how to do?